# Set HTTP Headers for Files in Public Folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to set `Accept-Ranges none` for video files that are requested from my `public` folder in Rails. The video file is not in my assets pipeline so the video simply lives at `/public/videos/example.mp4`. How can these HTTP headers be set in development mode? I tried editing the `config.public_file_server.headers` hash in `development.rb` but I don't believe this is the correct config.

```
config.public_file_server.headers = {
  'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=15768000",
  "Accept-Ranges" => "none"
}
```

Comment: Hey, did my answer solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know in Rails 4, besides `Cache-Control` no other response header can be set on files. That’s a limitation.

However [with changes in Rails 5](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/19135), you can set any header you want and that is the correct place to do it for development: `config.public_file_server.headers` in `development.rb`

However, for changes to take effect, you'll have to [create a development cache](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18875) using `rails dev:cache` before startig the server.

#### Demo:

**development.rb:**

```
if Rails.root.join('tmp/caching-dev.txt').exist?
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  config.cache_store = :dalli_store
  config.public_file_server.headers = {
    'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=172800',
    'Accept-Ranges' => 'none'
  }
else
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  config.cache_store = :null_store
end
```

**dev-cache and server**

```
$ rails dev:cache                                                                                                                
Development mode is now being cached.

$ rails s
```

**Request:**

```
$ curl -sI http://localhost:3000/car-images-silhouettes/back.png | grep Accept-Ranges                                                 
Accept-Ranges: none
```